# Apple AppStore Approval problems

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I am developing a GPS Tracking app which can come into security category in app Store. I have some problems regarding some things that I have used whether apple will approve it or not or there is some alternate for the problems

1. I have used

   ```
   bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
   bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];
   ```

Also using voip

```
BOOL backgroundAccepted = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:timer handler:^{

    [self beginLogging];

}];
```

Its keeping a function alive in background where I am sending some tracking data to the server

2. Next I have also played some empty sound to keep session alive
3. Clicking some photos in background without opening the camera in some time interval
4. Recording audio in foreground and background also on clicking on emergency button

This app is meant for security purpose and may be used by police. How to get this approve. Any modifications or alternatives in which apple can approve this. Any feature which I have to discard. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will get approved. Seems a bit dodgy. But if its only intended for a certain police force then how about distributing it only to them? Not via the App Store. Or in fact Apple do have some kind of enterprise app distribution on the App Store too now which limits you app to select people that you allow access to, so maybe thats a better alternative?

Comment: yes I know its a better way to distribute only to them. But any suggestions if I want to distribute to appstore. Do I have to take the government permission letter so that I can give it to apple?

Comment: @Rajan Ok I would get in contact with both the police and a good lawyer about this and maybe even Apple. These kinds of applications are not your everyday apps, there are laws/restrictions/checks which need to be made. When submitting your app to Apple, there is a notes/comments field, fill that in details and questions about the security of your app.

Comment: @Rajan But for your own protection, please contact a lawyer.

Comment: thanks about that. Which of the step can be eliminated according to you in the four steps I mentioned above to get it approved by apple. Please throw some light on these four steps specifically. And yes I have an enterprise certificate too.